# CD doesn't detect in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mount, cd-drive

I am trying to mount cd in ubuntu 16.04.And it doesn't detect automatically.Is there any command to access, cd in drive?

Answer (score 0):

There is options available under Settings > Devices > Removable Media. There should be an option for "CD audio", select "Open folder" in the drop down menu. Apologies if you have tried this already (kindly state what steps you have taken) or I misunderstood (you wrote mount which can allude to something different).